# EMAIL: In-Reply-To/References

Tags: python, smtplib

I am creating an email process in python using smtplib.

Got confused what value should I put in In-Reply-To/References Headers as per searching it should be the message id i am replying to, but upon reading the email from webmail I got this on one of the message that has reply:

> In-Reply-To: mid:3 References: mid:3

What does mid: 3 means?

Because right now I am having trouble replying to a message it always sending as new message